# mintinline inside tabularx causes "Missing Pygments output" error

Tags: luatex, minted

I'm working on a reference table for `printf` format strings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{ubuntu Mono}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
%opening
\title{\texttt{printf} Format String Reference}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Format specifiers}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X| }
  \hline
  \texttt{\%s} & \mintinline{c}{printf("Hello \%s", "World");} & \texttt{Hello World} \\
  \hline 
  \texttt{\%d}  & \mintinline{c}{printf("\%d cats", 5);} & \texttt{5 cats} \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I'm compiling with `lualatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "printf".tex`, the error I get is:

```
l.20 \end{tabularx}

! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

If I move the `\mintinline` out of the tabularx block, it works fine. If I change the package declaration for minted to `\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}`, it works (slowly) but the table doesn't resize properly and the end of the code sample overlaps the next column:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `tabularx` has severe restrictions about verbatim material in it. On the other hand a `tabularx` with `XXX`  can be easily realized with `tabular`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using `tabular` as suggested by egreg.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{ubuntu Mono}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
%opening
\title{\texttt{printf} Format String Reference}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Format specifiers}

\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|
                 p{\dimexpr\textwidth-6cm-6\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                 p{4cm}| }
  \hline
  \texttt{\%s} & \mintinline{c}{printf("Hello \%s", "World");} & \texttt{Hello World} \\
  \hline
  \texttt{\%d}  & \mintinline{c}{printf("\%d cats", 5);} & \texttt{5 cats} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Just a quick explanation for others, since I personally had to stare at this for a while to get what this is doing. The idea is to not use `tabularx` but `tabular` instead, since `tabularx` doesn't work with minted, but `tabular` works fine. The solution basically presents a way to simulate the `X` column type in a plain `tabular` environment.