# Using 'mintinline' inside 'tabu'

Tags: highlighting, minted, tabu, syntax-highlighting

This is pretty much a '17 version of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131371/using-minted-environment-inside-a-tabu-table?rq=1), since the solution provided does not work (anymore) in this case and neither does any of [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271900/mintinline-inside-tabularx-causes-missing-pygments-output-error) [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188003/minted-environment-inside-tabular/188163#188163) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187866/minted-inside-tabular), because `tabu` has its own rules.

The syntax highlighting works, using `mintinline` in the cell correctly highlights the code. There are no visible problems, it just throws the following error:
`Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using frozencache with a missing file. \end{tabu}`

Here is a short MWE and the compilation result:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabu,minted}
\begin{document}
    \mintinline{html}{<p>This works</p>}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {l | X[c] | c}
            Col1 & Col2                                   & Col3 \\
            \hline
            A    & \mintinline{html}{<p>This doesn't</p>} & B    \\
            C    & D                                      & E    \\
        \end{tabu}
        \caption{MWE Table}
        \label{tbl:table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of MWE compilation]

Applying the fix from the first linked answer does not work and does not alter the given error message. Other than that, I did not find anything helpful in neither the `tabu` nor the `minted` documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work: using `\tabuDisableCommands` to let `\mintinline` do something different and less complicated during the measuring phase and only do its thing during typesetting.

It has a drawback, though: `\detokenize`ing is not the same as verbatim input so this solution will fail in certain cases. In tables like the one of the OP where the column width doesn't depend on the actual content of `\mintinline` a safer `\renewcommand\mintinline[2]{}` would also do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,minted}

\tabuDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand\mintinline[2]{\texttt{\detokenize{#2}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\mintinline{html}{<p>This works</p>}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {l | X[c] | c}
    Col1 & Col2                                   & Col3 \\
    \hline
    A    & \mintinline{html}{<p>This doesn't</p>} & B    \\
    C    & D                                      & E    \\
  \end{tabu}
  \caption{MWE Table}
  \label{tbl:table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, this appears to be working fine, both in the MWE and in my working document.
According to the current `tabu` documentation, the command `\tabuDisableCommands` does "change the definition of some commands during the trial loops", which you are using to replace the meaning of `\mintinline` to a detokenized typewriter-text version. 
Am I correct in assuming that the trial runs are used to determine the column width and thus `tabu` is now using a less complicated macro for these runs to avoid the error, only applying syntax highlighting in the final run?

Comment: @Big-Blue yes, exactly

Comment: Thanks, I've marked this answer as accepted. Should future, similar problems with `tabu` arise in the future, I now know of a possible way to handle them.